# JSON.NET Deserialize string abbreviation into Enum

Tags: enums, json.net

I am just getting into JSON and all that and I ran into a snag. I am trying to parse a string abbreviation. I want to parse the string abbreviation into an Enum. Lets say my strings are:

'Apl', 'Orng', 'Bna'

Which for this example mean apple, orange, banana. Is there a way with JSON.NET to parse the abbreviated strings into an enum?

*Id prefer it if my enum can have the full name (Apple, Orange, Banana)

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. My incoming JSON (which I have no control over) is very terse and compact. I need to deserialize the string values into values of a couple different enums in app code. I've looked at custom converters, but don;t think I have it right...and there's not many good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're supposed to do this:

```
[DataContract]
public enum Fruit
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Apl")]
    Apple,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Orng")]
    Orange,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Bna")]
    Banana,

}
```

Comment: what happens if a new fruit comes from the server that's not in the enum?  E.g. "Pear"